# jsfl flash cs4 fl.trace() not working

Tags: flash, cs4, jsfl

I am running a jsfl script inside flash cs4 just using the "play" button with the jsfl file open.  What is bugging me is fl.trace() is not putting anything in the output window. I have tried fl.outputPanel.trace() and still nothing!

It is extremely cubersome to try and debug what is happening and was wondering if anyone has run into this issue or has a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that Filter level is Verbose. This option located on Output panel menu.